# Facebook API issue in Unity3D - "feature isn't available right now"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am making a game for Facebook. There is a feature for sharing resources (Life) like Candy Crush.

When I'm making call to FB.AppRequest, I'm getting

> Sorry, this feature isn't available right now. An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later.

It's happening only for the common users and not for the admin & Testers.

And I'm facing this problem for a month. Show me a direction to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: it might be worth ask facebook to look into this issue also - as its persisted for a month

Comment: Is your app in development mode in Facebook?

Comment: @ry8806 I'm keeping that as an last option to check with the Facebook. Thanks for the option though :)

Comment: @transporter_room_3 For testing this i'm making the game as live. Because things are working fine for the people I added as admin & testers

Comment: @user1511246 Are you testing this in the Unity Editor? Not all Facebook Methods are implemented in the editor, you need to deploy to a real platform first.

Comment: @zzzzzz.. I'm testing in Facebook canvas itself!! And i think I found the issue.. I'll update once it's confirmed..

Comment: Hey guys!! I got it working.. The problem is from my end.. Before I used the Facebook open graph object ID from Get Code API in Objects section. It worked only for administrator accounts. But for users we need to use the object ID from Object Browsers object ID. It resolved the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Spent 3 hours looking for this, indeed the correct Object ID is here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/object-browser
Facebook, update your documentation !